# How to Host a React App with 3D .gltf files?

Tags: reactjs

I want to ask on how can I host my react app. It is a 3d product configurator.

I tried to host it on AWS Amplify but the 3d models doesnt load

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host an application on aws amplify you have to create a build version of your app (assuming that it works already without any start issues meaning that you have a functional react app created with the command npx create-react-app).

Usually your react app runs on local host and it's basically like a test/development version of your app.  When you take it into aws it really wants a build version of your app.  The build command will generate everything you need for this.  Navigate to your react application folder and

Run the command

```
npm run build
```

This will create a folder that you can send to aws amplify.
When you go to the aws amplify site it'll ask you if you would like to build a website or host a website.

Select host and then it'll ask if you would like to push it from a repository like github.  For now lets just skip it and keep the deployment as simple as possible.  Deploy without git for now.

[image]

Next, we want to click on drag and drop so that you can manually select the file build folder that your npm run build command generated.

[image]

Look for the build folder that was generated and drag that folder into the aws area.  You don't actually have to click the 'choose files button'.  Sometimes the box glitches and won't let you drag anything outside of the box.  So what you can do is just open up your directories and manually find that build file in your folders.  Drag it from there to the aws zone at the bottom of the screen.

Give your AWS app a name and env name.

From there you can deploy.  Once you deploy it'll give you a site address.  Also before you make your build, be sure that all of the packages you need are installed.  I had an issue where my axiom commands were not working because I had not installed it prior to pushing my build.

So if your project depends on a certain npm package to run your .gltf files make sure that it is installed on your application.  You should see it inside the node modules folder (in your apps local directory not the aws one).

I think AWS uses the node modules folder to generate everything your project needs (But I am not 100% sure of this).  But it didn't work prior to me installing the package and pushing the build folder again to aws via drag and drop.

There are better ways to do this but this is what worked for me! Hope this helps to at least get your site up and running.  Also hope it helps with any package issues that might have been happening with your 3d models.  This is about as far as I can take you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar issue and I found another solution, in the GLTFLoader load function I changed the extension from the filename of my model from scene.gltf to scene.json, and that made the trick for me, hosting it in React with AWS Amplify hosting.

That tricks the amplify server into thinking this is just another binary file, threated the same way a JPEG will be threated (not confused with some kind of HTML webpage), and it will just resolve the path, and load the GLTF file normally.  I still don't know what exactly is causing a .GLTF file to behave differently than a JSON or JPEG, but the server is definitively resolving it as something else, some kind of script.  I you look into the Browser Developer Tools go to Network try to access the GLTF file direction with the URL for example: "https://YOURDOMAIN.SUBDOMAIN.com/images/scene.gltf  it will try to download other files like all.min.css, and others that have nothing to do with the GLTF.  But if you try to download just a 1.jpg from the public folder, it will download only that file.  That gave me the idea to change the extension to json, and then only the json file is downloaded and the contents of the GLTF file are now displayed as JSON.  At the end, the GLTF file seems to be a JSON file so it makes sense to change it to JSON, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just change .gltf to .json and in yaml file also

Comment: Please note that when making answers elaborate it more with sources until you get the privilege to comment to the questions. In fact, your response belongs to comments.